# How to trick AOT compliance check/TS compiler for given piece of code in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have an array of permissions looking like that:

```
permissions={
  view: "permissionName1",
  create: "permissionName2"
}
```

In component's contructor I have method that transforms permission names into boolean values pointing if you have or not given permission, so the resulting runtime permissions will look like this.

```
permissions={
  view: true,
  create: false
}
```

it works just fine when I need to use permission in template like this:

```
<ng-template *ngIf="permissions.view"> </ng-template>
```

Problem occures hovewer when I want to use permission in multiple condition if like

```
 <ng-template *ngIf="someSortOfCondition && permissions.view"> </ng-template>
```

This gives me an error when compiling with AOT saying that

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

I wrote this down from my memory so it may be not exact error message.It is quite clear that I want to use String as boolean in this conditional expression because at compile time `permissions.view` is indeed a string - it is a permission name not it's value.

Is there a way to either trick AOT analyzer to ignore that given case on my resposnibility? Permissions are initialized in constructor.

Comment: Have you tried `&& !!permissions.view`?

Comment: @yurzui i just saw that on github and will check that out! https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11425

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you write `permissions['view']` instead of `permissions.view` in your template

For AOT compilance check you can see [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6116) According to
[Filipe Silva](https://github.com/filipesilva)

> I agree that this would be super useful, but the right repro to ask
>   for it in is https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer. That's the addon to
>   tslint we use and that implements the Angular specific fules.